# Prevent unfilled fields in html form being sent

Tags: php

Not a php programmer, just html for me.  I am using a very large form with many text fields for quantity of items ordered.  I mean hundreds.  If you fill out one or two items (most would usually be around five) the form returns all results, with those chosen with answers, the rest are just blank, but it makes for a huge email result for just a few.  Is there code or a script or something, anything to prevent unfilled fields from being sent? It uses a PHP script to send via email.

Regards,
Bob Z.

Comment: You need to use something to the affect of `if(empty($_POST['variable_name'])){ die("You need to fill this field."); }`

Answer (score 0):

Execute this before parsing the $_POST values (where you add to the email message). Then whatever method you're using to get the POST variables into the body of an email, whether it be foreach, or print_r or a class, the empties won't exist.

```
$_POST=array_filter($_POST);
```

It will remove all keys whose values are == false, which includes empties. Note though, 0 == false too, so if you want to preserve those, you'll need this instead

```
function myFilter($var){
  return ($var !== NULL && $var !== FALSE && $var !== '');
}

$_POST=array_filter($_POST, "myFilter");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the form is using `METHOD="POST"` to transport the information to the processing script. What you want is to find the place, where all the form fields are out together. At this place you have to add the check, if the field value is empty or not.

Could be something like this:

```
// init email
$email = '';

// process fields
foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue)
{
     if ($value != '')
     {
         $email .= $fieldName . ': ' . $fieldValue . PHP_EOL;
     }
}  

// send email
...
```

If you post the php code which processes the forma and sends out the email, it would be easier to tell you the exact code that fixes your problem.

Greetings,
Richard

Comment: OK, but if this script is on the server and unavailable to me, I cannot add this to it.  Or is this for my form page some place?

Comment: Turns out (DUH!) the php script is NOT server side, I forgot I had it in a folder here.  For some reason, it will not let me paste the gdform.php from GoDaddy here, as much as I have tried to do it with indents and everything else.  Let me rename it, add in the lines you have above and try that filtering method above.  If it works, you will hear a loud "YAHOO!!!!!!!!!!!"

Comment: OK I tried that filter. What it did was sort of randomly prevent filled fields from getting through. For instance, I put a number for Quantity in every box in one section to start, as a test. Half of them returned with the number, the other half returned with nothing or simply were not sent. Checked the code, all is fine. Removed the filter, resent, all fields send.
So to recap, I just need one that only send fields that are filled out with a quantity, and not to send any field left blank.  
I could try to paste the script here, but it is too large and indents do not work.